# Backup to multiple locations in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup

Is it possible to configure Windows 7 Backup to backup the same content periodically (every 1 hour) to 2 separate hard disks? I have looked on Google but not had any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch script that does a xcopy /mir and have it mirror the source to the first backup location, then in the next line of the script, do another xcopy /mir from the first backup location to the second.  Schedule the batch script to run using Windows Scheduler.